# MVC5 / WEBAPI 2 routing HomeApiController to /api/home rather than /homeapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an existing webapi 2 application that needs a basic front end adding. The existing webapi controllers have been created in the Controllers directory root named xController yController.

```
Controllers
-XController.cs
-YController.cs
```

with the following route

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
            );
```

Each one of these controllers needs an accompanying MVC controller. What i would like to do is to rename the API controllers to XApiController YApiController and use routing to ensure existing usages of the service done break. Then I can add standard MVC controllers for the front end.

```
Controllers
-XApiController (previously XContoller)
-XController
-YApiController (previously YController)
-YController
```

Comment: Why do you need Web API app with MVC controllers? Web API is used for services and MVC app should use these services.

Comment: As I'm using ElasticBeanstalk for deployment I can only have 1 application. I don't think it warrants the hassle of splitting it up and creating 2 deployment pipelines and cost of duplicate infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just use the `RoutePrefix` attribute to do this? then you can call your controllers whatever you want and just have the attribute decide where it should be hosted, there are pros and cons to controlling your routing at the controller level but it seems to be a common use case, so for example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/home")]
public class SomeHomeController: ApiController
{
 // ...
}
```

Comment: I had to add Route attributes to each action but this did the job thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Controllers are separate types in each framework, and each framework can discover them regardless of their location (provided they have the right name). There is no reason to mess with routing to get your desired result. The only thing you need (assuming it is acceptable) is to put your controllers into a different namespace/folder so you can have 2 controllers (MVC and Web API) with the same name.

```
ApiControllers
-XController
-YController
Controllers
-XController
-YController
```

If you ask me, it is still better to keep the MVC and API controllers in a separate location even if you cannot deploy them as separate applications.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I had previously taken this approach, but wasn't 100% convinced, curiosity got me wondering if I could do it with routing. I'm still undecided which way I'm going to do it, but Grofits answer was more on point for what I was looking for, upvoted.

Comment: For the record, this should also be possible to do with convention-based routing (in one place) so you don't have to add an attribute to every controller through either `IHttpRoute` or by subclassing `HttpRoute`. You just need to change the controller route value on the incoming URL to add the "Api" part, and remove "Api" from the route value before generating the outgoing URL AFAIK.